# Using more than one ajax-form in one ejs Sails.js

Tags: sails.js, ejs, ajaxform

I am trying to add two forms in my ejs page using ajax-form tags and sails.js 1.0.0. Can you have multiple  tags inside one ejs page? In the first form the action is **updateMaplayers**  which looks at the controller update-maplayers.js file to update any records and the **maplayers** action on the second ajax-form looks at the maplayers.js controller to add a new record. When I try to run either actions they both fail if I have both . If I remove one of the ajax-form actions I I can submit. Does anyone have any examples?

My ejs file looks like

```
<div id="maplayers-main" v-cloak>
  <div class="container" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>Map Layers</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary float-right" @click="openAddMapLayerForm()">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div id="maplayers-container" >
        <% _.each(maplayers, function (maplayer) { %>
            <ajax-form action="updateMaplayers" :syncing.sync="syncing" :cloud-error.sync="cloudError" @submitted="submittedForm()" :handle-parsing="handleParsingForm">
                ......
            </ajax-form>
        <% }) %>

    </div>
    <div id="maplayers-add-container">
        <ajax-form action="maplayers" :syncing.sync="syncing"  :cloud-error.sync="cloudError" @submitted="submittedForm()" :handle-parsing="handleParsingForm">
          ........
        </ajax-form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<%- /* Expose locals as `window.SAILS_LOCALS` :: */ exposeLocalsToBrowser() %>
```

Comment: I think you need to distinguish your `submit` and your `handle-parsing`

Comment: Did you figure this out? I think I might have this need in the future.

Comment: I have not figured it out yet.